# "Interface not supported" ComException when setting RDOSession.MAPIObject

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, outlook-2016

My addin is encountering the error on some client machines when trying to set as RDOSession.MAPIObject= application.Session.MAPIObject in a C# based com add-in.

The code is executed in the main thread, RDOSession object is created through redemption loader, and the version of redemption being used is 5.16.0.4972.

All searches in regards to the error message point to the Outlook 2013 click-to-run error. But this is Outlook 2016 and the add-in is loaded in-session. Also, most other clients are not experiencing any issues.

I'm stumped with this, any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Does application variable come from the OnConnection callback? Or did you create it?

Comment: @JohnB: I am unable to provide any verifiable example as I am not able to replicate it locally.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: the application object comes from the OnConnection callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is after a recent Windows 10 upgrade (which wipes out some MAPI marshaling registry keys), try the registry patch from http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/Outlook_2013_C2R_fix.ZIP

Comment: Thanks for that @DmitrySteblechenko.
Is there anything I need to modify on those REG files to make them compatible with Outlook 2016?

Comment: No, as far as I know the keys are the same for both Outlook 2013 and 2016. Or you can reinstall Outlook.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry!! I shall test this out on the problem machine and get back with the result!

Comment: Hi Dimitry, I have not heard back from the client, so I assume the issue has been resolved. Thank you!!